# Top three records for each branch

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to write query for top three record(count and sum)  for each branch of company and I have branch costumers and contracts tables

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: Send your `Table Schema` and sample data and the result you expect.

Comment: What is you database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Branches](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [Something] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_5] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then, insert some data into it:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (1, 1, 10)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (2, 1, 15)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (3, 1, 20)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (4, 1, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (5, 1, 22)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (6, 2, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (7, 2, 32)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (8, 2, 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Branches] ([Id], [CompanyId], [Something]) VALUES (9, 2, 10)
GO
```

In the end, your query will be like this:

```
SELECT result.Companyid, SUM(result.Something) [Sum], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Branches WHERE CompanyId = result.companyid) AS [Count]
    FROM (
        SELECT companyid, Something, Rank() 
          OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId
                ORDER BY id DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM Branches
        ) result WHERE Rank <= 3
GROUP BY CompanyId
```

Schema:

[image]

First data:

[image]

Result:

[image]